# Kubernetes HPA not working: unable to get metrics

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, hpa

My pod scaler fails to deploy, and keeps giving an error of FailedGetResourceMetric:

```sh
Warning  FailedComputeMetricsReplicas  6s    horizontal-pod-autoscaler  failed to compute desired number of replicas based on listed metrics for Deployment/default/bot-deployment: invalid metrics (1 invalid out of 1), first error is: failed to get cpu utilization: unable to get metrics for resource cpu: no metrics returned from resource metrics API
```

I have ensured to install metrics-server as you can see when I run the the following command to show the metrics-server resource on the cluster:

```sh
kubectl get deployment metrics-server -n kube-system
```

It shows this:
[metrics-server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kB5ni.png)

I also set the `--kubelet-insecure-tls` and `--kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP` options in the `args` section of the metrics-server manifest file.

This is what my deployment manifest looks like:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: bot-deployment
  labels:
    app: bot
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: bot
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: bot
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: bot-api
        image: gcr.io/<repo>
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5600
        volumeMounts:
        - name: bot-volume
          mountPath: /core
      - name: wallet
        image: gcr.io/<repo>
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 800m
          limits:
            cpu: 1500m
        volumeMounts:
        - name: bot-volume
          mountPath: /wallet_
      volumes:
      - name: bot-volume
        emptyDir: {}
```

The specifications for my pod scaler is shown below too:

```yaml
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: bot-scaler
spec:
  metrics:
    - resource:
        name: cpu
        target:
          averageUtilization: 85
          type: Utilization
      type: Resource
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: bot-deployment
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 10
```

Because of this the `TARGET` options always remains as /80%. Upon introspection, the HPA makes that same complaint over and over again, I have tried all options, that I have seen on some other questions, but none of them seem to work. I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling the metrics-server many times, but it doesn't work.

One thing I notice though, is that the metrics-server seems to shut down after I deploy the HPA manifest, and it fails to start. When i check the state of the metrics-server the `READY` option shows 0/1 even though it was initially 1/1. What could be wrong?

I will gladly provide as much info as needed. Thank you!

Comment: A bit too late ... would be nice to check the logs of your metrics-server pod (kubectl logs -p)

Comment: hmm.. will keep this in mind, I fixed this a long time ago yes. Thank you though

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your bot-api is missing it's resource request and limit. your wallet has them though. the hpa uses all the resources in the pod to calculate the utilization

Comment: Thanks a lot, I managed to fix this a long time ago. I can't exactly recall what the issue was, but you're most likely right as to what the issue was, I didn't add resource quotas on the second container.